# uvm_config_db set issue

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am facing issue for set & get in uvm_config_db.

```
// Sequence extended from uvm_sequence, but not directly
// Sequence xa
   class xa;
     ...
     uvm_config_db #(bit)::get(null, get_full_name, "x", x); 
     ...
   endclass

// Testcase extended from uvm_test, but not directly
   class xb;
     xa a; // Object of sequence
     ...
     uvm_config_db #(bit)::set(null, {get_full_name, ".", "a"}, "x", 1'b0);
     ...
   endclass
```

But I am not able to get value in Sequence. There must be some path related problem, because if I broadcast it (by using * in 2nd argument of config_db), then I am properly getting the value in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if you call `get_full_name()` on you `xa` object you won't get the same thing as when you call `get_full_name()` inside your test + `.a`.

You have to make sure you set the context when creating the sequence. Since you didn't show us how you create your sequence, I'm just going to guess:

class xb;
     xa a; // Object of sequence
     ...
     a = xa::type_id::create("a", this);
     uvm_config_db #(bit)::set(null, {get_full_name, ".", "a"}, "x", 1'b0);
     ...
   endclass

This way `a` will get the appropriate context. You can also have a look at [this discussion](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/2261-how-to-pass-down-configuration-objects-to-non-uvm-component-objects-like-uvm-transaction/) for thoughts on how to pass stuff to sequences using the config DB.

Comment: Yes both won't be same. But I got my answer. Both 2nd & 3rd parameter must be same for set & get methods, apart from an exception in set (which is use of * to broadcast).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Almost true. You can use `*` anywhere inside set. Something like `set(null, "some.path.*, ...)` or `set(null, "some.path.*.some.more.path", ...)`.